# how to make a program ignore everything but the key word in users input?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, text-files

```
datadict = {}#open the file
with open('phoneproblemquery.txt') as file:

    for line in file:
        problem, answer = line.split('-')
        problems = problem.strip().split(' ')

        for item in problems:
            datadict[item] = answer

user_problem = input('What is the problem?:')
print(datadict[user_problem])
```

The text-file contains something like this:
***screen - replace screen.***
if I were to run this program and enter in 'screen' the program will respond **'replace screen'**. but, if I were to enter something like **'the screen'**(not just 'screen' alone) the program will give a '**keyError**' and won't work.
what would I need to do to if the user enters 'the screen' (instead of just 'screen') for the program to provide an output 'replace screen'. would I need to put the users answer into arrays? if so how?
Thanks!

1. update: 'the screen' was just an example. The user can enter in any
   form of way i.e 'screen is...' the keyword is screen. I would want
   the program to identify the key word from the users input and get
   the response 'replace screen'. ...  ;( desperate  for an answer...

Comment: Either you add `'the screen'` to the problems for that specific answer or you send the user input through a function which strips off auxiliary words such as `'the'`. At the moment if `'the screen'` was never listed as a problem (i.e. it got never stored in `datadict`) how do expect your program to know the answer? What if the user enters `'my screen'`?

Comment: You need to define what you consider a match in much more detail.

Comment: `user_problem.replace('the', '').strip()` will get rid of `'the'` but you might want to go for a more sophisticated approach to cover a wider range of possible user inputs that are related to "screen".

Comment: You could have a set of words to ignore and remove them from the user's input.

Comment: what I was trying to say is that if the user enters in any form of way i.e the screen, my screen, your screen ect. how could you make the program so that the keyword 'screen' is identified by the program (from what the user has entered) and still provide the output 'replace screen'

Comment: I understood what you were saying.

Comment: Is there a way to make the program ignore everything, but the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the program to pick keywords out of the user input and look for them in `datadict`. The difficulty with that is *picking out keywords*. A simple approach is to have regular expressions rather than simple keywords as the keys of your lookup dictionary. You will of course have to do the matching yourself: the dictionary lookup process won't do it for you.

```
import re

datadict = {}
#open the file
with open(r'phoneproblemquery.txt') as file:

    for line in file:
        problem, answer = line.split('-')
        problems = problem.strip().split(' ')

        for item in problems:
            datadict[re.compile(fr'{item}', re.IGNORECASE)] = answer

user_problem = input('What is the problem?:')
for regex, diagnosis in datadict.items():
    if regex.search(user_problem):
        print (diagnosis)
```

This will work, but in a more sophisticated implementation it might be better to put the regular expressions in the input data, rather than constructing them at runtime like I have done here. You are already allowing for something of the sort by having a space-delimited list if keywords in your input data. If you had regular expressions in the input instead, the same would apply, only instead of, say

```
keyboard kybd - replace keyboard
```

you would have

```
keyboard|kybd - replace keyboard
```

and in that event maybe a hyphen would not be the best delimiter. A carriage return might be better, since that can never appear in the input.

Comment: I tried out your program, unfortunately the program has a syntax error. I do not know how to fix it. if it is possible could you re-check the program ASAP and fix the program? if you do and it works you're a life saver! thanks.

Comment: When I run it, it doesn't have a syntax error. I think you may have introduced one when you copied it. If you report the line where you got the syntax error I might be able to help.

Comment: don't worry, I found the solution. more simple that you think!

Comment: Good luck with your solution. I didn't say mine was the only way, just one way.